# Select the last updated row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get the last updated row or record in an oracle database?
I want to ensure that a trigger is fired to check whether the last updated row has all uppercase entries, and if not convert them to upper case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write a trigger to do that:

```
create trigger mytable_trg
before insert or update on mytable
for each row
begin
   :new.col1 := upper(:new.col1);
   :new.col2 := upper(:new.col2);
end;
```

The trigger fires for each row inserted or updated, so there is no need to "find" the row.

Answer (score 5):

SQL is a set based language. If you are going to update several rows, there is no concept of "last updated row".

Making sure your API inserts UPPER(column_name) seems to be what you want.

You can also create a before row update trigger that does:

```
:new.column_name := upper(:new.column_name);
```

But that would be less efficient than offering an upper cased column_name in your API.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 4):

Many Oracle developers will try to tell you that triggers are a bad idea and should really only be used as a last resort to solve a problem if everything else has been tried. They often get used to do things that they were never really designed for. Some of the reasons for avoiding triggers are described by Tom Kyte in this [Oracle Magazine article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html).

In his answer Rob van Wijk is saying that the API used to modify the data should take care of making sure only upper case data is inserted. An alternative to this would be to create a check constraint on the column so that it is only possible to add upper case data.

```
SQL> create table my_temp_table (
  2  col_1 varchar2(50) check (col_1 = upper(col_1))
  3  );
Table created.
```

Create the table. Then try to insert some invalid and an error will be raised by the check constraint.

```
SQL> insert into my_temp_table values ('data');
insert into my_temp_table values ('data')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (EMIR_MONTHLY_PAL.SYS_C00113139) violated
```

Valid data will go in without a problem.

```
SQL> insert into my_temp_table values ('DATA');

1 row created.
```

Comment: +1 Good addition. A check constraint should not be forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `return rowid into` to get the rowid of the last updated row

in sqlplus:

```
create table t (id number, val varchar2(10));
insert into t (id, val) values(1, 'abc');

var rid varchar2(100);

update t set val = 'xxx' where id = 1 return rowid into :rid;

select * from t where rowid = :rid;
```

Comment: This only works in the special case when the statement updates only one row. You'll get an "ORA-24369: required callbacks not registered for one or more  bind handles" when there is more than one row.